# Displaying image from related CraftCommerce entry

Tags: relations, plugin-craftcommerce

Folks:

I'm using CraftCommerce. I have a main product and several accessories related to that product. Accessories have a title, description, price, and image.

Now, I have no problem pulling the title and description for the related accessories using this:

```
    {% for relatedProducts in product.relatedAccessories %}
       {{ relatedProducts.title }} - {{ relatedProducts.accessoryDescription }}
    {% endfor %}
```

Where I've got a problem is pulling the related image. If I use `{{ asset.getUrl }}` it pulls the first image from the main product entry rather than the image in the related entry. I have tried [Get image from related entries asset field](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/4220/get-image-from-related-entries-asset-field) and [How do I pull related entries and assets](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/630/how-do-i-pull-related-entries-and-assets/640#640)? without success.

Any assistance would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok first thing take the s off relatedProduct because each loop is over **one** relatedProduct ;) - then you can do something like this:

```
{% for relatedProduct in product.relatedAccessories %}
   {{ relatedProduct.title }} - {{ relatedProduct.accessoryDescription }}
   Url: {{ relatedProduct.yourAssetHandle.first().url }}
{% endfor %}
```

You should probably protect that by first checking `{% if relatedProduct.yourAssetHandle.first()|length %}` unless you can be completely certain you will have an asset (required field for example).

Comment: Perfect! That solved it. And a few other things for me to boot.

Comment: Glad to hear it - please accept it as an answer as I am shallow enough to desire points ;)